# Change directional arrow color when selected

Tags: css, list, button, hover, border

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ijCn.png) here is an image

can anyone help me out with this particular CSS Code. I need it to change the color of the directional arrows when selected i did it with the orange color, but as fas as the arrows i used ::before and After and then I added Class "btn-dir". I don't know what I'm missing. Please click on the image above

```
<span>Direction</span>
<ul class="inner-shadow dir" id="dir" data-attr="dir"><!--
--><li id="dw" data-val="dw" class="btn-dir grayd<%= (asset && asset.get('greekText').dir=='dw' || !asset) ? " selected" : "" %>"><span>down</span></li><!--
--><li id="ri" data-val="ri" class="btn-dir grayd<%= (asset && asset.get('greekText').dir=='ri') ? " selected" : "" %>"><span>right</span></li><!--
--><li id="dl" data-val="dl" class="btn-dir grayd<%= (asset && asset.get('greekText').dir=='dl') ? " selected" : "" %>"><span>downleft</span></li><!--
--><li id="dr" data-val="dr" class="btn-dir grayd<%= (asset && asset.get('greekText').dir=='dr') ? " selected" : "" %>"><span>downright</span></li><!--
--></ul>



CSS
li.grayd:hover, li.grayd.selected, li.grayd.selected:active  { 
    background: #c5c5c5; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, var(--main-color) 0%,var(--light-color) 90%);
}

.btn-dir, li.grayd.selected, li.grayd.selected:active {
    border-top: white;
}

/* inactive directions according to current section */
li.grayd.disabled { 
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

li.grayd.disabled:before, li.grayd.disabled:after { 
    --colored-icon: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: The code you have provided is not sufficient for me to reproduce the problem.